# Declined Flag on a clear NAA

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer

I typically refrain from posting these types of meta questions, mainly because I am well aware of the *typical outcome* that generally arise from posting these questions on meta, but this one is a little odd.

I had flagged [an "answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19507063/playing-youtube-video-with-start-and-end-time-using-youtube-api/53506612#53506612) *(10k req'd)* that was blatantly *not an answer*, and yet my flag was declined.

Here's the (now deleted) answer for those without 10k powers:

[image]

And here's the result of my flag for this answer:

[image]

Yet, this same answer was ultimately deleted by a moderator anyway. This was clearly asking a question as well as saying thanks to a prior answer. The URL that he was saying thanks to was copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19507833/5781745), and then he proceed to ask the question:

> But when i share it in mobile app like whatsapp , receiver can not play on android youtube app with start and end time. Is there any solution for this.

I currently have over 4200 helpful flags on SO, and I am not worried about one declined flag. I am just looking for the reasoning behind this decision. **Was I wrong to flag it**? If so, why did it get deleted by a mod anyway?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I handled a later NAA flag on the post by deleting it.

Your flag was declined 3 hours earlier - I suspect it was due to a mix-up as there was quite a number of flags on that post, and one of them was to be declined but due to a mishap the other flags were accidentally cleared. I can see that it was a mistake, please accept our apologies.

Comment: Mods really should have a way to reverse declines after the fact.

Comment: @FrankerZ True, especially when mods can change a "Helpful" into "Disputed" (by clearing a spam flag for instance), it's unfair to not have a "Declined" to "Disputed" route possible.

Comment: maybe you meant to decline the "this post is useful" flag :) I wonder how to make it right for OP without writing a meta post. There are a lot of them. Maybe it's not worth it. Keep up the good work Samuel.

Comment: I am not aware of a particularly good reason to worry about flag accept rate. When I finally did learn how to check I found mine was kind of bad and I only kind of care.

Comment: @FrankerZ The mods have a low enough error rate that mod errors aren't going to get anyone flag-banned who doesn't deserve it based on the totality of their flagging. As such, reversing bad flag declines would basically be a symbolic gesture, serving only to defuse any ill-will they might evoke from touchy users. There *is* real value even to that, of course. But beware the less visible downside: the potential for the community to squander effort litigating borderline cases on Meta, for no real purpose. On balance, I think that outweighs the upside, and I'm happy with the system how it is.

Comment: @Cœur Mods can convert Declined to Disputed, but not Declined/Disputed to Helpful

Comment: @Mark But you're forgetting one big thing: These flags don't disappear. They sit on your profile, and even have a drill down to show you only declined flags. It seems counter intuitive to continually show a user they've done something wrong, when in fact they haven't.

Comment: @FrankerZ Do we really *want* the mods to put in the work to fix every wrongly declined flag, though? It'd be one thing to flip ones that naturally result in Meta posts, but that's the tip of the iceberg. Out of my 2378 comment flags, 68 were declined, and *most* of those I've reflagged with a more detailed custom explanation spelling out why the comment should be deleted in greater detail, which was then accepted. That means most of those 68 declines were at least *arguably* erroneous. But is it a good use of my time, or the mods', to evaluate whether each of those declines merits reversal?

Comment: @Mark I'd personally like to know the mods thought process for declinations, as if they've done so, they're likely to decline othwrs for similar reasons. Having a way to reverse declines says hey "I messed up, it was a mistake", but bringing attention to it causes explanations to come out, to prevent similar errors from happening (On both sides, mod or flagger)

Comment: So what about automatically reverting a flag's status if the same (or any other?) flag type is accepted hours later on the same revision leading to a deletion of the answer? There is a big enough group of erroneus declines that would be caught by that. Then we can still ignore the rest because it would be too much trouble.

Comment: Just to be clear, @Machavity... Mods can convert *any* flag result to "disputed"... for spam and abusive flags. However, they can't do so selectively - if the option is used, *all* spam or abusive flags on a post will be marked disputed: those formerly declined, those formerly helpful, those aged away... Those flags carry consequences that other flags do not, hence the special treatment - but it's not for the benefit of the flagger.

Comment: @Shog9 Interesting. That explains a lot. Had a spam flag on a Charcoal report once that was [edited in the grace period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307637/) before the flag was handled. Mod declined it, but one of the Charcoal mods changed it to disputed. I didn't know anything could be changed to disputed.

Comment: In practice, that's usually reserved for cases when a post is deleted as spam but shouldn't have been, @Machavity - but there's nothing preventing the reverse from occurring as well.